# descobrir o menor primo maior que o numero n em C

Tags: c, if, while, condição

O exercício pede o seguinte: escreva um programa que lê um número n, e então imprime o menor número primo maior ou igual a n.

Minha solução é foi receber um número; analisar se é primo; se for primo a var primo recebe um. Caso não, entraria no while para receber o próximo numero e o programa deveria analisar para ver se é primo ou não. Mas o código não funciona. Quais pontos eu estou errando ?

```html
int main(void) {
  int num,i, j, ediv=0, primo=0;

  
  printf("Digite um numero\n");
  scanf("%d", &num);

   for(i=2; i<num*num; i++){
    if(num%i==0){
      ediv = ediv + 1;
    }
  }
  if(ediv<=2){
    primo = 1;
  }
  if(primo==1){
    printf("Este numero e primo");
  }else{

while(primo!=1){
   
  printf("digite o proximo numero");
  scanf("%d", &num);
  for(i=2; i<num*num; i++){
    if(num%i==0){
      ediv = ediv + 1;
    }
  }
  if(ediv<=2){
    primo = 1;
  }
  }
  printf("o menor primo seguinte e %d", num);
    }
  return 0;
```

Comment: Seu programa faz outra coisa e não o que foi pedido. Simplesmente leia um número. Só um número. E retorne o primeiro primo menor ou igual a ele. Isso sugere um `for` descendo de `N` até `3`. E naturalmene pulando os pares, já que 2 é o único primo par e 3 já é primo.

Comment: Obg! Corrigi o meu programa. Obrigada pela contribuição!

Comment: Franklin Almeida, aqui apareceu uma [tentativa sua de edição em uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/399993), outra resposta havia sido anteriormente  removida, e as modificações que sugeriu não fazem sentido como uma edição. O pergunto, não preferiria apresentar e explicar aquele código como uma solução a sua pergunta?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Não me parece que o objetivo do exercício seja o utilizador ter de continuar a introduzir manualmente o próximo número. A lógica correta parece-me ser verificar se o número é primo e caso não seja testar o número imediatamente a seguir e assim ciclicamente até encontrar o "menor primo maior do que o número n".

Neste exemplo tens uma função que retorna se um número é primo ou não (1 ou 0) e um ciclo que vai testando os números começando em n e incrementando-o até encontrar um que seja primo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isPrime(int n) {
    int prime = 1;

    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        prime = 0;
    } else {
        for (int i = 2; i <= n/2; ++i) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                prime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return prime;
}

int main(void) {
    int n, primo = 0;
    printf("Digite um numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while (primo != 1) {
        primo = isPrime(n);
        n++;
    }

    printf("Menor numero primo maior ou igual a n: %d\n", n-1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, obrigada. Eu acho que consegui fazer. Mas não utilizando função, pois meu prof não chegou nesse tópico ainda. Obrigada pela contribuição novamente.